# Saving to Local Database Graph?

Tags: swift, database, cosmicmind

I can't seem to persist the data that I'm saving. 
Whenever the app gets closed, when I open the app again the synced entity from graph doesn't really persist again.

How do you persist and have only one instance of graph and retrieve the previous entity created when you open up the app again?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic setup to persist an Entity of type "User".

```
// create a user Entity
let user = Entity(type: "User")
user["name"] = "Daniel"
user["age"] = 33

let graph = Graph()

graph.sync()
```

And searching for your entity:

```
let graph = Graph()

// setup the search criteria 
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "User").where(properties: ("name", "Daniel"))

// synchronously search
let entities = search.sync()
```

That's it :)